# How can I add to LTSpice the MC34063 model?

Tags: ltspice

I found the MC34063 moden in the eevblog forum: [link](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/simulate-mc34063-on-ltspice/?action=dlattach;attach=38508)

How can I add it to the LTSpice to if I want to make a buck or boost converter it appears in for.example in the power product list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the .asy file to the location where the LTspice symbol files are kept, I.e., `C:\Users\Me\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\sym`, and the .lib to `C:\Users\Me\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\sub`. Restart LTspice.