# DC-DC converter not simulating correctly

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, ltspice, boost, solar-energy

I am trying to design a solar charge controller to charge a 12V battery, my solar panel is made of 9 cells that are 5W and 0.5V per-cell. I would like to make a booster circuit to get the voltage up to 13-14 in order to charge the circuit.

I am planning on using a [`MC34063A`](https://www.ti.com/product/MC34063A) for this and I found multiple examples of what I am trying to do.

1. The first arrangement I have tried was [Here](https://www.twovolt.com/2016/08/23/28v-output-from-12v-dc-input-step-up-dc-dc-converter-using-mc34063/), but when I get the components into `LTSpice` and try and simulate it, I get very different results than what I am expecting.
2. The second is [here](https://www.eleccircuit.com/circuit-battery-voltage-regulator-by-mc34063/), but again when I get the components into `LTSpice` I am getting very different results than what I am expecting to see.

I got the spice model for the `MC34063A` from [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/317578/how-can-i-add-to-ltspice-the-mc34063-model)

Here is a picture of my current spice model, which is representative of the second configuration.
[image: Circuit]

Here is the picture of the results of the simulation.
[image: results]

I am hoping to see 12V at C3 and currently, I am getting the source voltage. Just over 5V.

If someone is able to show me the errors of my ways I would be greatly appreciative for the help

Comment: It would help a lot if you edit your question to tell us what you are expecting, and what you are seeing.

Comment: And, in the absence of PTT, as a start you probably want to design the circuit to regulate the panel input voltage to 0.5V/cell, rather than regulating the output voltage.  (You really want to have some priority regulator that says more or less "first keep the panel voltage above this limit, then keep the battery current below this limit, then keep the battery voltage below this limit" -- if I got that right (meaning, if you get your diodes pointed the right way in your regulator) then you should end up with something that charges the battery pretty good.

Comment: And -- 12V battery, but what chemistry?  Lead-acid?

Comment: @TimWescott I have changed it so that I mentioned what I would like to see and I added a picture of the simulation currently.

Comment: As far as the overall Circuit, I think I have an idea for regulating the current going to the battery but I thought first I would have to get the voltage up above 12V in order to have the battery charge, and then send that into a circuit that will monitor and limit the current of the battery. And I thinking a 12v battery that is Lead-acid

Comment: Is everything else working as intended? Are you getting a switching signal on the base of your BJT?

Comment: @Stiddily everything else seems to be working. I am getting a switching signal on the base.

Comment: Hah -- I didn't even notice that you haven't simulated the panel realistically.  Have you looked at the collector voltage and current of Q1?  Transistors turn off slowly unless you actively remove charge from their bases, and IIRC the MC34063 isn't designed as a gate (or base) driver -- you may not be turning Q1 off fast enough, or even at all.

Comment: @TimWescott I have set Q1 to be a TIP31 from `onsemi` as it has on the website, but it made no difference on the simulation.  The voltage on the collector goes up to about 5.3V at its max and then drops down to 5V at 1.9ms and continues at 5V. The current says around 0 and at that same moment it quickly jumps up to around 25uA and then ossocialtes back down to 0

Comment: For some reason you're not turning Q1 on.  What's going on at the base of Q1?  What's your PWM frequency?  It should be PWM-ing and (T'oh) you should have a current-limit resistor in there.  The circuits that I've seen that use an external transistor with the 34063 have a circuit with two or three transistors to actively drive the base of the main transistor.  Without those you should probably have a series pass resistor from pin 2 to the base, and a resistor from base to ground.

Comment: @laxer If you look at the datasheet examples, you will see a pull-down resistor at the base of the external BJT. (The IC uses an internal Darlington between SWC and SWE -- obvious naming convention here.)

Comment: @TimWescott and jonk, you two called it. that was exactly what was going on! I placed a resistor there and It started to PWM-ing and went up to 12V after about 4ms and stayed flat. Thank you for your help and for talking me through what was going on.

Comment: @laxer No problem. All of us have gone through the same experiences. I'm just glad it helped get things back on track for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DC-DC converter not simulating correctly

I think you'll find that the simulation is correct.
The datasheet for the [MC3046A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc34063a.pdf) shows the schematic (9.1.1) you require when using an external transistor:

[image]

Without the Base/Emitter resistor the capacitance of the Q1 junction (both EB and CB) will cause your Q1 to switch off very slowly. This will decrease the backemf you get from the series inductor so limiting the voltage output.